# get View of default dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to implement ProgressDialog in DialogFragment and use it as a Fragment. My onCreateDialog looks like this:

```
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String message = getArguments().getString("msg");

    ProgressDialog dialog =  new ProgressDialog(getActivity());


      dialog.setMessage(message);
      dialog.setTitle("");
      dialog.setCancelable(true);
      dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
      dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
      return dialog;
}
```

According to android developers, to use this dialog as a Fragment, I must implement onCreateView, which returns view object. The question is, how do I get View of such dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with just the onCreateDialog.
If you want to create a more complex view and fragment, you should create a method such as:

```
public View onCreateView( . .. ) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_xml_id, null);
    return view;
}
```

See this blog for more:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html